# Know when an operation has been completed

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I'm parsing a JSON data with AFNetworking lib:

```
-(void)getAbs:(NSString*)link{

    NSString *linkk=@"http://localhost:8080/Students/StudentWS/nb_abs/?student=";

    NSURL *url= [ NSURL URLWithString:linkk];


    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        arrayofStudentID=[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"id"];
        arrayofStudentName=[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"name"];
        arrayofAbs=[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"abs"];


        [[self stdTableView] reloadData];

    } failure:nil];

    [operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
        //HUD Code


    }];

    [operation start];

}
```

I want to verify if `arrayofStudentID`has 0 elements after executing the operation.

```
if([arrayofStudentID count]==0){
//some code
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: wat you want to verify doesn't understood

Comment: You can do it in the completion block - the question is what you do after the check...

Comment: @Wain: I added the completion block but it's no longer displaying the results `[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Completed:");
            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        
    }];`

Comment: @Wain: I printed the count of the array and it's null. What could be the problem ?

Comment: @androniennn did you try printing the JSON object to see if your array is in there?

Comment: @AaronBrager: I printed the JSON object (NSMutableArray), and it's returning nil in the completion block.